# How can I disable all mouse functions in MacVim?

Tags: vimrc, macvim, mouse

Is there a way that I can use the `'mouse'` option to disable all mouse functions in MacVim?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To disable all mouse functions, you can simply put this in your `vimrc` file:

```
set mouse=
```

For more, see `:help 'mouse'`.

Comment: Actually, set mouse= does not do anything in a local vimrc if lets say "set mouse=a" has been set by default before. This is somewhat annoying.